# C# POCO/Proxy classes for Salesforce REST API

Tags: c#, .net

I have a newbie question.

Is there a tool or utility to generate proxy classes for Sales force objects to use with REST or SOAP Api?
Something similar to what Dynamics CRM has XrmToolkit or CrmSvcUtil.exe.

Comment: In the sample of toolkit, is class Account manually created or generated?

Comment: REST - take a look at the (unofficial) [SF .NET toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET). You have to manually create the proxies. With SOAP, you can use your favorite .NET approach/library to connect and auto-create the proxies, e.g. via [WCF service provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.